# How to repeat "copy range (A1:A5) to Range B with transform (column to row)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a data in the Range A

```
1 a1
2 a2
3 a3
4 a4
5 a5
6 b1
7 b2
8 b3
9 b4
10 b5
```

and I copied A1 to A5 to Range B10, B1 to B5 to Range B11, C1 to C5 to Range B12 and so on with transform (from column to row)

```
a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
b1 b2 b3 b4 b5
n1 n2 n3 n4 n5
```

for one datafile, the Codes look like this:

```
Sub XX
    Range("A1:A5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B10").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

How should I repeat this process in VBa with "for next" for the whole datafile?

I cannot figure out how to define "i".

Comment: why not copy A1:Z5 (or whatever) and paste-transform the whole lot at B10?

Answer (score 0):

You want to know how to define `i`? I assume you mean `i` which is commonly used to name an integer? If so, then I'm thinking you want to use VBa but have more control?

This should do what you want, or give you a good start

```
Option Explicit
Sub DoTheThingThePersonWantsWithExcel()

Dim resultsRow As Integer
resultsRow = 10 ' this is where the results will be shown

Dim resultsColumn As Integer
resultsColumn = 66

Dim currentRow As Integer
currentRow = 1

Dim previousCharacter As String
previousCharacter = ""

Do While (Range("A" & currentRow).Value <> "")

    Dim currentValue As String
    currentValue = Range("A" & currentRow).Value

    Dim currentCharacter  As String
    currentCharacter = Left(currentValue, 1)

    If previousCharacter = "" Then
        previousCharacter = currentCharacter
    End If

      If (currentCharacter <> previousCharacter) Then
        previousCharacter = currentCharacter
        resultsColumn = 66
        resultsRow = resultsRow + 1
      End If

      If (currentCharacter = previousCharacter) Then
        Range(Chr(resultsColumn) & resultsRow).Value = currentValue
        resultsColumn = resultsColumn + 1
      End If

    currentRow = currentRow + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Before

[image]

After code is run

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show you two ways to do this. The first is just giving you what you asked for -- showing you how to incorporate a for loop into the code you already have. The second way is how I would go about doing this in a more efficient way.

**Copy/paste method:**
First, here's your adapted code. The key is to first identify how much data you have. This information is stored in the variable `n`. Second is to figure out how to index your for loop so that you only select the chunks of 5 you want without repeating or skipping anything. Finally, you must figure out how use these same index values to print your output to the appropriate row. So, here's the code:

```
Sub XX()
    Dim n As Long
    n = [COUNTA(A:A)]
    For i = 1 To n Step 5
        Range("A1:A5").Offset(i - 1, 0).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("B10").Offset((i - 1) / 5 + 1, 0).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

First, `n` is calculated using the worksheet function `COUNTA`. This works because your data is contiguous and starts at row 1.

Next is the for loop which goes from 1 to `n` by 5s -- so, for the first iteration `i = 1`, for the second iteration `i = 6`, for the third iteration `i = 11`, and so on.

The key to selecting the right data is using the `.Offset` method of the `Range` object. This method allows you to shift the range a specified number of rows and columns. You want to shift the selection to be copied down 5 rows each iteration. An offset of `i - 1` gives you what you want.

Finally, you have to use `.Offset` to adjust the output down 1 row for each iteration. Since `i` is stepping in 5s, and you don't want your output to be spaced 5 rows apart, you must scale down `i` by 1/5 as the offset. Here `(i - 1)/5 + 1` gives you the row offset you need.

**Array processing method:**
Here's another way to approach the same problem that does not use the copy/paste method. It performs the transformation on VBA arrays instead of working directly on the worksheet. This is much more efficient, and for large data, there will be a very noticeable difference in run time.

```
Sub Reorganize()
Dim colData() As Variant, i As Long
Dim outData() As Variant, j As Long
'Store all data from column in array for fast processing
colData = Range("A1").Resize([COUNTA(A:A)], 1).Value
'Size output array to match data
ReDim outData(1 To Int((UBound(colData, 1) - 1) / 5) + 1, 1 To 5) As Variant
'Loop through array and print values to corresponding indices in output array
For i = LBound(colData, 1) To UBound(colData, 1)
    outData(Int((i - 1) / 5) + 1, ((i - 1) Mod 5) + 1) = colData(i, 1)
Next i
'Print reorganized data to sheet
Range("B10").Resize(UBound(outData, 1), UBound(outData, 2)).Value = outData
End Sub
```

Most of the differences between the two ways are noted in the comments in the second Sub. The indexing in the loop is a little more complicated in the latter, but the idea is essentially the same in both.