# How can I tranpose multiple columns to single column with repeated ID?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

How can I do the below action?
From left to right with Formula or VBA?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Show us your effort and then we can see where it has gone wrong. Sadly your quesiton reads more like "do my work for me" and is likely to be downvoted. You can edit your quesiton to include this information :)

Comment: under Related topics you can find a similar problem / solution. That I believe @Dave has answered in the past. There should be a good amount of info to maybe reverse engineer to do the opposite.  https://superuser.com/questions/793069/how-to-repeat-copy-range-a1a5-to-range-b-with-transform-column-to-row?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/793069/how-to-repeat-copy-range-a1a5-to-range-b-with-transform-column-to-row?rq=1

Comment: The proposed duplicate looks like simple transposing.  That's different from this question.

Answer (score 2):

With data like:

[image]

In **G1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$9999,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0))
```

In **H1** enter:

```
=INDEX($B$1:$E$1,MOD(ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0)-1,4)+1)
```

In **I1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$2,ROUNDUP(ROWS($1:1)/4,0)-1,MOD(ROWS($1:1)-1,4))
```

copy these cells downwards:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*There are many ways to work on this, but in terms of **flexibility**, I would use `POWER QUERY` here which can **effortlessly** do the automation thus saving **time and effort**. `Power Query`, available in `Windows Excel 2010+` and `Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)`*. Watch the demonstration for reference. Takes less then **2 minutes** to perform the task.

---

[image]

---

To use Power Query follow the steps:

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"ID"}, "Date", "A/B/C"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"A/B/C", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

Using Modern Excel Version aka `MS365` with dynamic array formula can also be accomplished, using one single input entry. The below formula can be made short, for demonstration, the variables shown by steps.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, Table1[#All],
     _Dates, TAKE(_Data,1,-COLUMNS(_Data)+1),
     _IDs, TAKE(_Data,-ROWS(_Data)+1,1),
     _Context, DROP(_Data,1,1),
     _TransformOne, TOCOL(IFS(_Context<>"",_IDs&"|"&_Dates),3),
     _TransformTwo, TOCOL(_Context,3),
     _Output, HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(_TransformOne,"|"),TEXTAFTER(_TransformOne,"|"),_TransformTwo),
     _Headers, HSTACK(TAKE(_Data,1,1),"Date","A/B/C"),
     VSTACK(_Headers,_Output))
```

---

- `_Data` -->  A variable to hold the entire range of data, including your headers, therefore the only piece of formula you'd have to change; `Table1[#All]`
- `_Dates` --> Extracts the dates from the headers using `TAKE()` function. `TAKE(_Data,1,-COLUMNS(_Data)+1)`
- `_IDs` --> Extracts the ids from the data body using the `TAKE()` function. `TAKE(_Data,-ROWS(_Data)+1,1)`
- `_Context` --> Extracting the data body context using `DROP()` function `DROP(_Data,1,1)`
- `_TransformOne` --> Transforming the data i.e. repeating both `IDs` & `Dates` to n times using `TOCOL()` & `IFS()` and restructuring vertically.  `TOCOL(IFS(_Context<>"",_IDs&"|"&_Dates),3)`
- `_TransformTwo` --> Transforming the `_Context` into one single array using `TOCOL()` - `TOCOL(_Context,3)`
- `_Output` --> Outputs the data as per the requested output, here `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()` is used to split the `_TransformTwo` into two columns. -- `HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(_TransformOne,"|"),TEXTAFTER(_TransformOne,"|"),_TransformTwo)`
  `_Headers` --> Merging the headers using `HSTACK()` -- `HSTACK(TAKE(_Data,1,1),"Date","A/B/C")`
- `VSTACK(_Headers,_Output)` --> Using `VSTACK()` function to append the `_Headers` and the `_Output`.

---

Also, instead of using the above, place the above in `Name Manager` and name it as `UNPIVOT()`, so that it can be used anywhere in your workbook. In this particular case, use

`=UNPIVOT(Table1[#All])`

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**[Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckkHrIXqIIzQQ0lPJ?e=tQvYRZ)**

---